# How do I connect a CakePHP 2.x app to an AWS RDS instance with SSL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-rds, cakephp-2.3

Considering CakePHP 2.x's database config docs:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html

And the fact that instead of providing **ssl_key**, **ssl_cert**, and **ssl_ca**, AWS RDS provides an **rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem**:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

How can we connect a CakePHP 2.x app to an AWS RDS instance with SSL?

Is it possible? Has someone done it?

How do you refer to the single `pem` file?

I've had it working fine with a server that does work with the 3 files, but this single file thing I can't figure out.

Comment: Can you not manually split the `pem` file up?

Comment: I started that route, but the file became more than 3 straight forward things. It was more like 10 or 15 different new files and none of them were clearly ca or key or whatever. How are we supposed to figure out what's what when the file is so full of different things?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html